# Horizontal centering of section name

Tags: horizontal-alignment, sectioning, alignment

Consider, as a starting, point the code below.

I would like to have the multi-lined section name horizontally centered, but I have been unsuccessful.

This type of centering is to be applied only on *certain* section names and not on all section names.

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{my section, my section, my section, my section, my section, my section, my section, my section, my section, my section, my section, my section}

\newpage
\thispagestyle{empty}
\topskip0pt
\vspace*{\fill}
\section*{my section, my section, my section, my section, \linebreak {\centering my section, my section, my section} \linebreak {\centering my section, my section, my section}}
\vspace*{\fill}
\newpage

This section...

\end{document}
```

Comment: I've removed the "align" tag.  That is specific to a multiline math display, not relevant here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a class, that provides such a feature, e.g.,

```latex
\documentclass[emulatestandardclasses]{scrartcl}

\begin{document}

\let\raggedsection\centering
\section*{centered section, centered section, centered section, centered
  section, centered section, centered section, centered section, centered
  section, centered section, centered section}

\let\raggedsection\raggedright
\section*{left-aligned section, left-aligned section, left-aligned section,
  left-aligned section, left-aligned section, left-aligned section,
  left-aligned section, left-aligned section, left-aligned section,
  left-aligned section}

\let\raggedsection\raggedleft
\section*{right-aligned section, right-aligned section, right-aligned section,
  right-aligned section, right-aligned section, right-aligned section,
  right-aligned section, right-aligned section, right-aligned section,
  right-aligned section}

\let\raggedsection\relax
\section*{justified section, justified section, justified section, justified
  section, justified section, justified section, justified section, justified
  section, justified section, justified section}

\end{document}
```

[image]

or add a package, that supports change of the alignment, e.g.:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{sectsty}

\begin{document}

\sectionfont{\bfseries\centering}
\section*{centered section, centered section, centered section, centered
  section, centered section, centered section, centered section, centered
  section, centered section, centered section}

\sectionfont{\bfseries\raggedright}
\section*{left-aligned section, left-aligned section, left-aligned section,
  left-aligned section, left-aligned section, left-aligned section,
  left-aligned section, left-aligned section, left-aligned section,
  left-aligned section}

\sectionfont{\bfseries\raggedleft}
\section*{right-aligned section, right-aligned section, right-aligned section,
  right-aligned section, right-aligned section, right-aligned section,
  right-aligned section, right-aligned section, right-aligned section,
  right-aligned section}

\sectionfont{\bfseries}
\section*{justified section, justified section, justified section, justified
  section, justified section, justified section, justified section, justified
  section, justified section, justified section}


\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Perfect, @cabohah! Thanks a lot!